# How to test svelte input reactivity?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, svelte, svelte-testing-library

I wrote a svelte component `App` in which you can write a sentence in an `input` and the sentence will be render in a `h1`.

**App.svelte**

```html
<script>
  let sentence = "Hello world";
</script>

<main>
  <h1>{sentence}</h1>
  <input
    value={sentence}
    type="text"
    on:input={(value) => {
      sentence = value.target.value
    }}
  />

</main>
```

But when I tried to test this behaviour using [@testing-library/svelte](https://testing-library.com/docs/svelte-testing-library/intro), the input is not reactive and the text in `h1` is still `"Hello world"` (but the value in the input has changed according to the first `expect`).

**App.test.js**

```js
import { render, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/svelte";
import App from "./App.svelte";

it("should write in input", async () => {
  const { container } = render(App);
  const input = container.querySelector("input[type=text]");

  await fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: "test" } });

  expect(input.value).toBe("test"); // ✅
  expect(container.querySelector("h1").textContent).toBe("test"); // ❌
});
```

**Jest error message:**

```
Expected: "test"
Received: "Hello world"

   8 |   await fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: "test" } });
  10 |   expect(input.value).toBe("test");
> 11 |   expect(container.querySelector("h1").textContent).toBe("test");
  12 | });
```

You can check this behaviour using the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/test-svelte-input-fqgnx?file=/App.test.js:302-335).

Has someone an idea why this test is failing?

Comment: Just wondering, do you get the same behavior if you use `<input bind:value={sentence}>`?

Comment: @CarlosRoso Yes I get the same behaviour see [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/test-svelte-input-forked-9b9l3?file=/App.svelte)

Comment: I wonder if that's related to the fact that it's triggering a `change` event when Svelte is subscribed to the `input` event. Try changing it to `on:change` and you'll see the test passing. Now, the ideal situation would be to have `fireEvent` triggering an `'input'` event.

Comment: @CarlosRoso You're right it's working using `fireEvent.input(...)`. Thanks for your help please write it as an answer so I can validate and upvote it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

Use `fireEvent.input(...)` as you suggest in the comments.

**Original thought:**

I wonder if that's related to the fact that it's triggering a `change` event when Svelte is subscribed to the `input` event. Try changing it to `on:change` and you'll see the test passing. Now, the ideal situation would be to have `fireEvent` triggering an `'input'` event.

Answer (score 0):

And if you import at the beginning of the file:

```
import { screen } from '@testing-library/dom'
```

and at the end you put this:

```
 expect(
      await screen.findByText('test'),
    ).toBeVisible()
```